# GitHub search code in repositories filtered by main language

Tags: github

Here is example

[Searching](https://github.com/search?q=mkDerivation%20%20openssl&type=Code) code "mkDerivation openssl" gives 16k+ results for language Nix

Is there a way to filter these results based on repository dominant language for example C++

Basically I want to find C++ repos that use Nix like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can see in the GitHub docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax
you can add at the end of the search

```
 language:<the_language>
```

for example in your case to search cpp files that fit "mkDerivation openssl" you should search:

```
mkDerivation openssl language:C++
```

or you can search for whatever you want but after this click the language you want it to be like in the next picture:
[example of choosing language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2UNc.png)

the place marked with red is the language option, pick one of them